# FinalizeArray Exemplo

Tags: array, delphi

Estou tentando limpar um vetor após executar um procedimento, já que preciso usar o mesmo vetor pra fazer próximo loop do procedimento.
Após bastante pesquisa encontrei a procedure adequada pra limpar o vetor sendo `FinalizeArray`.

Localizei o método nessa documentação
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.FinalizeArray

Porém não encontrei um exemplo pra entender a forma correta de aplicar.

Se eu executar o comando dessa forma:

```
FinalizeArray(Titulosdelete,Titulosdelete,count);
```

Na hora do Debug vou ter o erro:`invalid pointer operation`

Alguém pode me dar um exemplo correto acredito que estou errando o segundo parâmetro.

Comment: O que você quis dizer com limpar o vetor? Apenas o preencher com zeros ou o liberar a memória associada ao vetor inutilizando sua referência?

Comment: Apenas o preencher com zero. Como é um vetor dinâmico, o que desejo é zerar todos os endereçamentos e iniciar tudo de novo a partir do posição [0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para liberar a memória referenciada por um vetor use o método:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.FinalizeArray

```
FinalizeArray(Titulosdelete, TypeInfo(Titulosdelete), Length(Titulosdelete));
```

Para preencher um vetor com algum valor especifico(zeros) https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/21564:

```
FillChar(Titulosdelete, SizeOf(Titulosdelete), 0);
```